# Subfolder or setting the language from content in Polylang?

Tags: seo, wordpress

I am creating a web page in two languages and I'm using for that purpose the Wordpress Polylang plugin. This plugin offers different ways to create a multilingual URL structure, like using subfolders, subdomains or setting the language from content. In my case, I have doubts between using a subfolder or setting the language from content.

Using a subfolder for each language:

- myweb.com/article
- myweb.com/es/articulo

The other alternative is to **set language from content**:

- myweb.com/article
- myweb.com/articulo

[image]

The only disadvantage I know for the second alternative is that is not possible to set up geotargeting in the Search Console.

One disadvantage of using subfolders is that if the plugin is deactivated the URL structure is lost and the backlinks are also lost. (https://polylang.pro/doc/url-modifications/)

Which is the most recommended way? Which is better for SEO? There are more disadvantages when setting the language from content?